# how to determine date when service pack was applied to SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server

For an instance of SQL Server 2005/2008, how can one determine the date and time when a service pack was applied to the instance? Is there a system table or view that stores that information?

Comment: I *think* you would need to get this out of the Windows event log (assuming it goes back far enough)

Comment: in this case, it doesn't go back that far, but thanks anyway .. I guess I figured there would be some sort of table, or even a registry entry, showing date of application of service pack

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\XXX\Setup Bootstrap\Log. The summary.txt and the individual SP log folders have all the details.

Comment: Along these same lines for full history you can look in the Setup Bootstrap\Update Cache and note the KB####### folders and dates.  Each KB relates to the CU or Patch and the folder date is typically the install date (unless install failed).  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2936603

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link

Where you understand

**How to determine the version and edition of SQL Server and its components**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Answer (score -1):

View installed updates should help determine that.

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features and click on View Installed Updates

Answer (score -1):

SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')

Comment: Your answer can be much more better and valuable with a description of what you are suggesting.